# Улучшение страницы справки "Что означает статус вопроса «закрыт» или «требует правки»?"

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Заголовок: What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?
Ссылка на текущую версию на английском: https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

---

#### Why are some questions marked "on hold"?

Questions that need additional work or that [are not a good fit for this site](/helpcenter/on-topic) may be put on hold by experienced community members. While questions are on hold, they cannot be answered, but can be edited to make them eligible for reopening.

Questions that are edited within five days of being put on hold are automatically added to a reopening queue for community review. Questions that are not reopened within five days will change from `[on hold]` to `[closed]`.

Each closed or on-hold question provides a reason that helps the original poster (or other community members) know what they'd need to do in order to get the question reopened.

These are the categories of questions that may be closed by the community:

- [**duplicate**](/help/duplicates) - the fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place

  > This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question.
- **[off topic](/helpcenter/on-topic)** - each community decides which specific topics are and are not allowed on their site.

  > This question does not appear to be about $Topic [within the scope defined by the community](/helpcenter/on-topic). What's on- and off-topic is not always intuitive, so it may be necessary to reword the question to fit this site's scope after reviewing the community guidelines.

  Consider editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if you believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope.
- **unclear what you're asking** - sometimes we need more information in order to help solve your problem

  > Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

  Edit your post to be more specific about what you're looking for, and be sure to address any concerns that other users brought up in the comments.
- **too broad** - if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are *correct*), then it is probably too broad for our format

  > Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.
- **primarily opinion-based** - [discussions focused on diverse opinions](/help/dont-ask) are great, but they just don't fit our format well.

  > Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than on facts, references, or specific expertise.

#### Who can put questions "on hold"?

Users with $ReputationRequiredToClose reputation can cast up to $CloseVotesPerDay close votes per day. When a question reaches $CloseVotesNeededForClosure close votes, it is marked `[on hold]`, and will no longer accept answers. Those users may vote to reopen questions the same way. Each user may only vote to close and reopen a given question once. (For example, if you vote to close a question that is closed and then later reopened, you cannot vote to close it again.)

Moderators may close or reopen any question with a single vote.

For more about reopening questions, see ["What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen a closed question?"](/helpcenter/reopen-questions)

#### Why are some questions marked "closed"?

Questions are marked `[on hold]` for the first five days after closure to encourage edits and improvements to the question. If a question is edited by the original poster when it is marked `[on hold]`, it will automatically be placed in a [review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues) to be considered for reopening. If it is not reopened within five days, the `[on hold]` notice automatically changes to `[closed]`.There is functionally no difference between an `[on hold]` question and a `[closed]` one; neither can be answered until it is re-opened, but they both allow comments, votes and edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заголовок: Что означает статус вопроса «закрыт» или «требует правки»?

Ссылка на текущую версию на русском: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

---

#### Почему некоторые вопросы «требуют правки»?

Вопросы, [не соответствующие тематике сайта](/help/on-topic) или критериям качества, могут быть отмечены как «требующие правки» опытными участниками сообщества. На вопрос «требующий правки» нельзя опубликовать ответ, но можно внести улучшающую правку, чтобы в дальнейшем открыть его повторно.

Вопрос автоматически попадает в очередь на повторное открытие, если в течении пяти дней с момента получения статуса «требующий правки», он был изменён. Если вопрос не был открыт повторно в течение пяти дней, его статус изменяется с `[требует правки]` на `[закрыт]`.

Каждый закрытый или требующий правки вопрос сопровождается пояснением, которое помогает автору (и другим участникам сообщества) понять, что именно следует сделать для того, чтобы вопрос был открыт повторно.

Причины закрытия вопросов.

- **[дубликат](/help/duplicates)** — основной целью закрытия является сбор всей информации, относящейся к вопросу, в одном месте.

  > Такой вопрос задавали ранее и на него уже получен ответ. Если представленные ответы не являются исчерпывающими, пожалуйста, отредактируйте этот вопрос, пояснив, в чём состоит его отличие, или задайте новый вопрос.
- **[не по теме](/help/on-topic)** — каждое сообщество само решает, какие вопросы допустимы, а какие — нет.

  > Скорее всего, данный вопрос не соответствует тематике сайта согласно правилам, описанным в справке.

  Если вы полагаете, что при другой формулировке вопрос может соответствовать тематике, возможно, стоит отредактировать вопрос или оставить комментарий с предложениями по его улучшению.
- **непонятна суть вопроса** — иногда сообществу требуется больше информации, чтобы помочь вам в решении вашей проблемы.

  > Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

  Отредактируйте ваш вопрос, чтобы он как можно более конкретно описывал то, что вы пытаетесь решить. Пожалуйста, не забудьте ответить на все комментарии, оставленные другими участниками.
- **вопрос слишком общий** — если для ответа на ваш вопрос требуется написать целую книгу или существует множество верных ответов, он, скорее всего, не соответствует формату вопросов и ответов.

  > В текущем виде на ваш вопрос невозможно дать лаконичный ответ. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, какие технологии используете и что хотите видеть в ответе.
- **необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать однозначно верный ответ** — [обсуждения, основанные на различных мнениях](/help/dont-ask) — это прекрасно, но они тоже с большой вероятность не подходят для формата вопросов и ответов.

  > Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Для получения ответа перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ, либо удалите вопрос вовсе.

#### Кто может отметить вопрос как «требующий правки»?

В день, участники с репутацией $ReputationRequiredToClose и более могут голосовать до $CloseVotesPerDay раз за закрытие вопросов. Если вопрос получает $CloseVotesNeededForClosure голосов за закрытие, его статус изменяется на `[требует правки]`. Эти же участники могут проголосовать за повторное открытие вопроса таким же способом. Каждый участник может отдать всего один голос за закрытие или повторное открытие одного вопроса. (Например, если вы проголосовали за закрытие вопроса, который затем был закрыт, а после повторно открыт, вы не сможете ещё раз проголосовать за его закрытие).

Модераторы могут закрывать и открывать вопросы без голосования.

Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с разделом [«Что делать, если я не согласен с закрытием вопроса? Как его снова открыть?»](/help/reopen-questions) для получения подробной информации о повторном открытии вопросов.

#### Почему часть вопросов помечена как «закрытые»?

Автор вопроса, отмеченного как `[требующего правки]`, имеет возможность внести улучшающую правку в течении пяти дней. Если вопрос, отмеченный как `[требующий правки]`, будет улучшен автором, он автоматически попадет в [очередь проверок](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work), в которой он может быть открыт повторно. Если вопрос не был открыт повторно в течение пяти дней, состояние `[требует правки]` автоматически изменяется на `[закрыт]`. Функциональной разницы между состояниями `[требует правки]` и `[закрыт]` нет; в обоих состояниях на вопроса нельзя дать ответ, но можно комментировать, голосовать и редактировать.