# Вы сломали мой StackOverflow, часть 3: “текст задачи” — это не отсутствие кода!

Tags: обсуждение, причины-закрытия, нытьё

В очередной раз вижу, что этой причиной закрытия злоупотребляют:

> **Сообщение содержит лишь текст задачи, в котором нет описания проблемы, либо вопрос чисто формален («как мне выполнить это задание»)**. Для повторного открытия вопроса, добавьте описание конкретной проблемы, поясните, что именно не получается, в чём вы видите проблему.

Последний пример: [Алгоритмы. Сортировка. Поиск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/722986/178988)

Как я уже указал в комментарии, автор вопроса расписал, что нужно сделать (отсортировать по трём полям), как он пытается это сделать (через три сортировки) и что именно у него не получается (выделить подмассивы, которые надо сортировать второй и третьей сортировками). Неужели для ответа на вопрос действительно нужна стена кода с этими попытками? В вопросе и так всё есть. И фраза, что нужно именно на си (а не на плюсах, например), вопросу в общем-то не вредит.

Тем не менее, на вопросе висит уже 3 голоса за закрытие.

[Не все вопросы без кода плохие](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3851/178988), а с причиной закрытия надо что-то делать. Да и вообще, я не считаю, что любой вопрос, содержащий только текст задачи, надо закрывать.

PS: Связанные вопросы от @Squidward:

- [Вы сломали мой StackOverflow, часть 1: "опросники" должны умереть!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1924/178988)
- [Вы сломали мой StackOverflow, часть 2: "вопрос неясен" — это не MCVE/SSCCE!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1931/178988)

Comment: А я предупреждал! %(

Comment: Так ведь не закрыли же. Надо сначала статистику получить по закрытиям с данной причиной, и посмотреть сколько из них не закрыты не совсем корректно.

Comment: Минус. Для отказа от причины вовсе одного примера злоупотребления недостаточно. Давайте ещё.

Comment: @D-side, примеров много, но я их не запомнил.

Comment: Вот ещё [хороший пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/723040/)

Comment: @alexolut, да там еще и отвечающего заминусовали. Совсем нехорошо

Comment: @avp ибо нефиг "отвечать" на всякий шлак. Вопрос, который я назвал "хорошим примером", на самом деле следует удалить вовсе, если он не будет отредактирован. Только вот наличие "ответа" усложняет этот процесс.

Comment: @Qwertiy, вот ещё пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/723462/227016

Comment: @alexolut, я думал, уже все, бесповоротно пропал сайт... Но, раз уж отвечающего "разминусовали", то может есть еще у него шансы.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/721741/178988 - пример.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/722914/178988 - закрыли

Comment: @avp в примере от alexolut даже не задача — там приказ. «Зашифруйте мне вот это и вон то, да пошевеливайтесь».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6193/178988

Новая причина для закрытия звучит так:

> **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

---

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6205/178988 - **уже неактуально**

> данная причина закрытия была удалена по запросу модератора как используемая не по назначению

<sup>ответ дан 20 часов назад Nicolas Chabanovsky ♦</sup>

Более подробное обсуждение в вопросе [Причина "Сообщение содержит лишь текст задачи" применяется не так, как задумывалась изначально](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6189/178988)

Answer (score 3):

### В тексте причины никаких* проблем нет.

Никакого отношения к "вопросам без кода" эта причина не имеет ни в тексте, ни в мотивах.

[Изначально эта причина задумана для отсева надуманных и искусственных проблем](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5043/181100). И это назначение текст вполне отражает. Но поскольку эта причина практически всегда подходит для "вопросов", содержащих исключительно неразобранные учебные задания (и, реально, [была введена для противодействия вопросам вида "решите мне задачу"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4992/181100)), сложилась, возможно, не вполне нормальная **практика применения**.

Она тянет *некоторых* участников ставить голос по этой причине на любые вопросы, связанные с решением лабораторных работ и школьных заданий, не разбираясь.

[Приведённый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/722986/178988) — вполне практическое учебное задание о часто возникающей проблеме. Причём автор вопроса уже весьма далеко зашёл в её решении — у него есть теоретически работоспособный алгоритм. Неэффективный, правда. Очередная XY-проблема. Но всё это (учебный характер, XY) не делает вопрос достойным закрытия.

---

Эта причина закрытия ещё довольно новая и не все участники могут быть в курсе норм её применения. **Сейчас единственная широко известная норма "закрывать домашки", но она неверна.** И если видите, что кто-то использует эту причину неправильно, [предоставьте ссылку на более обстоятельное описание причины](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5043/181100). Возможно, стоит [подготовить текст для справки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5922/181100), чтобы помочь в распространении норм, принятых на Мете.

Любые инструменты, будучи выданными широкому кругу лиц, хоть кем-то да будут использоваться неправильно. Система должна быть к этому готова. Stack Overflow ставит высокий порог для единоличных решений, от сколько-нибудь широкого круга лиц требуется аж 5 голосов, чтобы произошло закрытие.

Пока что в вопросе приведён единственный пример злоупотребления этой причиной закрытия. И до закрытия он не дошёл, значит защита "несколькими голосами" от редких ошибок работает как задумано. Накопившиеся там голоса [со временем поотваливаются](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting), если новых не поступит. Посему, принимать какие-либо меры против этой причины вижу преждевременным (кроме точечного воздействия на отдельных участников ссылками на сообщения с Меты).

---

* Окей, есть, но не относящиеся к обсуждаемой теме.

Comment: давайте вещи своими именами называть. Есть опытные участники, которые не любят вопросы типа ["работа за автора"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/231/23044) вне зависимости полезен ли вопрос для будущих посетителей или нет. Вот [предсказание как этой причиной закрытия злоупотреблять будут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5043/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment18459_5043) (я не проверял насколько верное фактически на данный момент пока)