# Неужели правки, противоречащие намерениям автора, бывают допустимы?

Tags: обсуждение, правки

Суть (случилась в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/733202)) такова:

- Автор вопроса спросил, например, как получить «второе ноября»
- Была принята правка (видимо, по невнимательности), явно противоречащая намерениям автора, исправляющая «второе ноября» на «2 ноября» (это две разные задачи, которые решаются сильно по-разному)
- Вскоре после этого появился ответ, как получить «2 ноября», от участика, который не заглядывал в историю и не знал об некорректности правки
- Другой участник в историю заглянул и, недолго думая, «второе ноября» на место
- После чего этому другому участнику сообщают, что якобы «не следует менять вопрос так что делает неверными существующие ответы»

С чего это вдруг стало можно менять суть вопроса без согласия автора? С чего это вдруг суть ответа стала превыше сути вопроса? Вопрос не является общим, автор с правкой не соглашался, он может «2 ноября» и без нашей помощи получить может, а не осиливает именно «второе ноября». По-моему здесь следует отредактировать/удалить ответ, а вопрос вернуть на место. Или хотя бы сделать вопрос общим.

Comment: Я вот тоже думаю, если было бы уже 5 ответов по текущему варианту вопроса, то точно не стоило бы откатывать вопрос. А так как ответ всего один, то можно и откатить.

Comment: думаю если было бы 5 ответов - было бы проще сказать автору изивини, задай вопрос ещё раз, в этом другое ответили)

Comment: Все правильно, ответ скорее (насколько я понимаю, сам автор пока ничего не написал) всего не соответствует первоначальному вопросу.

Comment: Да там исходный вопрос можно было бы вовсе закрыть а не исправлять...

Comment: @PavelMayorov почему это? Он онтопик, конкретен, несёт практическую пользу (и не только для ТСа).

Comment: @PavelMayorov [Qwertiy обиделся бы :)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5953/)

Comment: @D-side вот именно потому, что в итоге вот так вышло. Если бы автор исходного вопроса не ушел в закат - его слово было бы в текущем споре решающим. А так без его участия вопрос исправили, ответили, а теперь решаем как так получилось.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

В первую очередь — вопрос принадлежит автору. Движущей силой для создания вопросов Stack Overflow избрал решение проблем конкретных участников. Поэтому правки должны продолжать относиться к исходной проблеме, с которой столкнулся автор вопроса.

Политика "не вносить в вопрос правок, делающих неактуальными ответы" касается в первую очередь автора, поскольку вносить правки, меняющие смысл вопроса, а потому делающие ответы неактуальными, вносить имеет право только он. По большей части, это защищает от ситуаций, в которых автор вынуждает отвечающих уделить его вопросу дополнительное время, что часто приводит к потере потенциально хорошего содержимого.

На этом фоне [принятие правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/205831), меняющей смысл вопроса — явный сбой, ломающий аккуратно связанные между собой нормы Stack Overflow. И он повлёк за собой парочку других сбоев.

Между тем, требовать от каждого отвечающего перед ответом ознакомиться с историей вопроса весьма самонадеянно и ненадёжно со стороны сообщества.

---

Из предположения, что ответ нельзя натянуть на исходную проблему, ответ и исходная проблема несовместимы, а вопрос и ответ достаточно хорошие, чтобы предпринимать меры по сохранению обоих, **кому-то придётся задавать новый вопрос**.

- Автор может оставить вопрос в виде, соответствующем уже опубликованному ответу, и оформить новый, соответствующий исходному. По-хорошему, автор тут ни в чём не виноват, и требовать от него лишних действий с нашей стороны довольно нагло. Зато за ним остаётся не-совсем-его вопрос, потенциальный дополнительный источник репутации.
- Ответивший может оформить вопрос-самоответ, в котором опубликовать свои труды. Содержимое потеряно не будет, вопрос автора уцелеет в изначальной форме. Ответивший, конечно, тоже не виноват, что автор не уследил за вопросом, но должен понимать, что автор спрашивал не об этом.

Оба варианта предусматривают небольшую моральную компенсацию тому, кто признан пострадавшим: небольшой потенциальный источник репутации в форме не-вполне-своего вопроса.

Только синхронизируйтесь где-нибудь, чтобы не получилось три вопроса :)