# Обязаны ли люди, отвечающие на вопрос, прежде чем ответить проверять что все предыдущие правки вопроса соответствуют намерениям автора?

Tags: обсуждение

Я увидел [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/733202/3) как получить "2 ноября 2013 года." и [ответил на него](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/733293/23044).

Позже другой участник, [изменил вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/733202/4) на *"второе ноября 2013 года"*, что больше соответствует [начальному намерению автора вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/733202/1), что сделало существующий ответ неверным.

Следует ли отказаться от политики «не следует делать правки, которые делают существующие ответы неверными»? Выиграют ли будущие читатели от того, что изменённый вопрос не соответствует опубликованному ответу? Stack Overflow это не форум взаимопомощи, не в этом [цель](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/23044) — Stack Overflow это cайт вопросов и ответов — основная аудитория это [посетители из гугла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/site-analytics/traffic-sources).

Обязаны ли люди, отвечающие на вопрос, прежде чем ответить проверять что все предыдущие правки вопроса соответствуют намерениям автора?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Неужели правки, противоречащие намерениям автора, бывают допустимы?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6181/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8b)

Comment: Давайте не приумножать сущности, а разбирать проблему там, где ее первоначально подняли.

Comment: @FoggyFinder я бы не торопился закрывать этот вопрос. Все-таки он куда больше похож именно на вопрос чем на возмущенный крик. К примеру, по вашей ссылке нет ответа, а тут - есть.

Comment: @PavelMayorov на мой взгляд, качество вопросов аналогичны, но тот был задан первым. В добавок, @jfs был проинформирован о вопросе на мете, но вместо того, чтобы решать проблему поспешил представить свое видение ситуации (или как вы это называете `возмущенный крик`)). Но так или иначе сейчас есть одна проблема и два вопроса.

Comment: Это вообще два разных вопроса про одну и ту же ситуацию. Пусть живут оба, ссылками они связаны, а закрывать дубликатом нет смысла.

Comment: Кажется, освещая ситуацию, я [случайно ответил на оба](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6184/181100).

Answer (score 10):

Нет, не обязаны. Но после того как несоответствие текущей формулировки вопроса изначальному намерению автора вскрылось - надо принять его во внимание, а не лезть в драку и не устраивать войну правок-откатов.

---

> Следует ли отказаться от политики «не следует делать правки, которые делают существующие ответы неверными»?

Следует различать правки вопроса и откаты/исправления некорректных правок вопроса.

Comment: вы себе противоречите. Как же не обязан, если по вашему мнению: *"надо принять во внимание"*, то есть выбросить старый ответ, написать новый. Это всё равно что сказать: вы не обязаны выполнять правило X, но если вы его нарушите мы вас накажем.

Comment: @jfs никакого противоречия. Удаление некорректного ответа или его переписывание - это не наказание, а устранение аварии.

Comment: подумайте немного. Факты: 1- ответ является верным для опубликованой версии вопроса, на момент публикации ответа [до отката] 2- вы сказали: *"нет, не обязан"* [проверять предыдущие правки] 3- вы говорите: *"ответ некорректный"* [для предыдущих версий вопроса]¶ Отсюда противоречие: если не обязан проверять предыдущие правки,  то важно только соответствие ответа версии вопроса на момент публикации  этого ответа. В этом смысле ответ "корректный". Но вы говорите что ответ "некорректный". Всё ещё не видите противоречия?

Comment: @jfs нет, важно лишь соответствие ответа вопросу на текущий момент. Потому что мы строим сайт с полезной информацией, а не играем в бюрократию.

Comment: значит если я сейчас поменяю вопрос на другой, то вы удалите свой ответ?

Comment: @jfs так делать не рекомендуется (ссылку уже приводили вы сами). Но если вы будете сильно настаивать - да, я удалю этот ответ, перенеся его в новую тему, а тут оставлю тревогу модератору.

Comment: значит вы таки любите бюрократию, когда она в вашу  пользу :) Ладно, из обсуждения ясно, вы почему то боитесь признаться, что ваш ответ говорит, что человек публикующий ответ обязан проверять все предыдущие редакции вопроса, чтобы напрасно ответ не писать. (не ясно чего боитесь). Но то, что не признаёте ошибку, когда она неопровержимо доказана, говорит что вы за человек (но это уже за рамками тематики Stack Overflow).

Comment: @jfs не вижу связи. К примеру, публикуя свой ответ я не проверял историю вашего вопроса. Как это говорит о том что я ее был обязан проверить?

Comment: я уже объяснил в первом же комментарии. Аргумент по кругу пошёл. Во втором комментарии я разжевал по пунктам. с каким фактом вы не согласны (номер скажите)

Comment: @jfs у вас какие-то проблемы то ли со временем в ваших аргументах, то ли с причинностью... Я не понимаю как ваши аргументы противоречат тому что я написал.

Comment: ответ либо "корректный" (случай, когда *не обязан* историю смотреть), либо "некорректный" (не соответствует предыдущей версии вопроса). Вы пытаетесь утверждать одновременно, что *не обязан* проверять (факт: ответ корректный для версии вопроса, когда ответ был опубликован) и что ответ "некорректный" (факт: не соответствует предыдущим версиям вопроса  намерению автора). Получается ответ одновременно корректный и некорректный. Противоречие можно устранить, если сказать, что если не хочешь удалять ответ, то проверяй предыдущие редакции вопроса. Другими словами, действительный ваш ответ: да, обязан

Comment: @jfs вы не учитываете, что признак корректности ответа может меняться со временем

Comment: вы пытаетесь в сторону увести вопрос. Нет, утверждение является ли ответ корректным для фиксированной версии вопроса не зависит от времени (если редакция говорит от "2 ноября", то ответ о "2 ноября" является корректным сегодня, завтра, вчера и в любое другое время). Вы всё-таки определитесь: вы все ещё пытаетесь утверждать что человек не обязан читать предыдущие редакции вопроса? если как ваш ответ сейчас говорит: "нет, не обязан" то ответ с "2 ноября" корректен. "не обязан", значит, что вину за прошлые правки вопроса на отвечающего не возлагаем — вы это по-другому понимаете?

Comment: @jfs для фиксированной версии вопроса - да. Но вопрос-то не фиксирован и может изменяться, намеренно или нет.

Comment: @jfs *"не обязан", значит, что вину за прошлые правки вопроса на отвечающего не возлагаем* - совершенно верно

Comment: поэтому и существует политика: *«не следует делать правки, которые делают существующие ответы неверными»* Ситуация: вопрос + ответ соответствуют друг другу (всё хорошо). Пришёл человек и изменил вопрос так, что тот перестал соответствовать ответу -- кто виноват?

Comment: @jfs в данном случае ситуация, которую вы описали как "все хорошо" - нифига не хорошо, ибо противоречит намерениям автора вопроса.

Comment: снова по кругу пошли. Вы говорите: отвечающий не обязан читать историю вопроса читать, чтобы выяснять соответствует ли текущая правка намерениям автора. Вы говорите: что "совершенно верно", что "вину за прошлые правки вопроса на отвечающего не возлагаем". Но при этом считаете оправданным, что ответ следует удалить (наказать отвечающего), так как "противоречит намерениям автора". Я могу только предположить, что вы дурика специально включили (делаете вид, что не понимаете логику). Поэтому без меня продолжайте дискуссию.

Comment: @jfs вы почему-то пропустили первый же мой комментарий: **удаление ответа - это не наказание**

Answer (score -1):

Если участник планирует потратить время, которое он считает существенным для предоставления ответа и вопрос уже содержит некоторое количество ревизий, то безусловно лучше подстраховаться и посмотреть их внимательнее. Невыполнение этого требования может привести к публикации решения на совсем другую проблему, особенно если правка была принята без утверждения её автором вопроса (как это произошло в упомянутом случае). В такой ситуации, ответственность в первую очередь лежит на утвердивших ошибочную правку. Но как я уже сказал в начале, автор ответа должен быть готов к тому, что ответ придется поменять, порой радикально, либо удалить вовсе.