# Что за user****( * == число)?

Tags: поддержка, идентификатор-участника, удалённый-пользователь

Пример:
[Вы сломали мой StackOverflow, часть 3: “текст задачи” — это не отсутствие кода!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5953/%d0%92%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-stackoverflow-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-3-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d1%83%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0#comment22762_5953)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

При удалении пользователя его посты обезличиваются и ссылка на профиль заменяется на текст

```
user{id}
```

Comment: Каким образом такие "удаленные" пользователи пишут вопросы и комментарии?

Comment: @Эникейщик, когда они пишут вопросы и комментарии, они еще не удаленные :-)

Comment: Да я только что с таким разговаривал :)  И на первой странице несколько свежих вопросов от таких юзеров12345.

Comment: @Эникейщик, ссылку на пример, :)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1056597/282277

Comment: @Эникейщик, это не удаленный участник :-) просто не заполнил имя :)

Comment: Ну понятно тогда.